# Update google apps user with python

Tags: python, google-apps

I am trying to update a user with `service.users().update`. It returns a 200 response but don't change anything.

```
results2 = service.users().update(
    userKey='116908937914240107065',
    fields='id,name/fullName,primaryEmail',
    body='{"primaryEmail":"name@domain.org"}'
    ).execute()

print('id: {0} | Email: {1} | Nome: {2}'.format(results2['id'],results2['primaryEmail'], results2['name']['fullName']))
```

Comment: maybe a bug in google??

Answer (score 0):

Did it!
Just wondering why Response = 200 when there is an error in code...

Without ' ' between {"primaryEmail":"name@domain.org"} solved this...

```
body={"primaryEmail":"name@domain.org"}
```